# Displaying All Tables Created By a User PL SQL Procedure

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure that displays all of the tables created by a specified user. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_tables
@username VARCHAR(50),
@result  varchar(100000)  OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN    
   -- Execution section 
   Set result = SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = @username;


EXCEPTION    
  -- Exception section 
     WHEN no_data_found THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('User does not exist'); 
   WHEN others THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('Error!'); 


END;
```

I was wondering if this is the right path, and how I should go about completing this task

Comment: The "@" and "Set" are SQL-Server syntax, not Oracle; so no, this isn't the right path.  NO_DATA_FOUND could occur for a couple of reasons not just an incorrect user name.  I suggest a FOR loop with a CURSOR and display user content row-by-row in the loop.

Comment: "All tables created by" that are still in existence? This will not show you tables created by USER three months ago and **dropped** last week; do you care? If you don't, you are only looking for tables currently *owned* by `USER`.

Comment: I believe they mean a specified user, not just USER.  If that were the case they could go with user_tables instead of all_tables.  Of course all_tables gives you only those tables you have permission to see.

Comment: If what's wanted is all the table names owned by a specific user then what's needed is the DBA_TABLES view. ALL_TABLES is actually a misnomer meaning all tables the current USER can access. With ALL_TABLES user1 and user2 most likely get different, but, still correct results for the same query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint

```
BEGIN
    FOR tn IN (SELECT table_name FROM all_tables /*WHERE owner = vc_User_Name*/)
    LOOP
        -- Display some stuff
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tn.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```